# How to list all the barButton Items in a mdichild form from mdiparent RibbonForm?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, gridcontrol, ribbon-form

I'm trying to list inside a gridcontrol in a form mdichild loaded in a xtraTabbedMdiManager1 all the barButtonItems from the ribbonpages in the mdiparent RibbonForm.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Clear();
dt.Columns.Add("ID");
dt.Columns.Add("PAGE");
dt.Columns.Add("GROUP");
dt.Columns.Add("BARBUTTON");
DataRow dr;
RibbonControl parentRibbon = ((RibbonForm)this.MdiParent).Ribbon;
RibbonPageGroup group = parentRibbon.Pages.GetPageByName("ribbonPage1").Groups.GetGroupByText("ribbonPageGroup4");            
foreach (DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItem item in parentRibbon.Controls)
{
dr = dt.NewRow();
dr["BARBUTTON"] = item.Name;
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
gridControl1.DataSource = dt;
```

But It doesn't run it. It shows me this error System.NullReferenceException. Please help me. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this :

`ItemLinks` will give you all `BarButtonItem` access. you can read this article for more information :
https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraBars.BarButtonItemLink.class

Please remember that, Form1 is parent form and ribbonControl1 is parent form ribbon control.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Clear();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID");
    dt.Columns.Add("PAGE");
    dt.Columns.Add("GROUP");
    dt.Columns.Add("BARBUTTON");
    DataRow dr;
    XtraForm frm = (XtraForm)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
    RibbonControl parentRibbon = (RibbonControl)frm.Controls["ribbonControl1"];
    List<BarItemLink> var = parentRibbon.Pages.GetPageByName("ribbonPage1").Groups.GetGroupByText("ribbonPageGroup1").ItemLinks.ToList();
    foreach (DevExpress.XtraBars.BarItemLink bar in var)
    {
        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["BARBUTTON"] = bar.Caption; // bar.Item.Name; // bar.DisplayCaption;
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I m  in a mdichild, how can I access to ribbonControl1 since here?

Comment: Yes you can get access of parent form controls from child form. Check below codes.
`XtraForm frm = (XtraForm)Application.OpenForms["Form1"];
            RibbonControl parentRibbon = (RibbonControl)frm.Controls["ribbonControl1"];`

Here `Form1` is the parent from.

Comment: Thanks, I modified GetGroupByName instead of GetGroupByText. So How can I go through all the pages because I want to get all the barbuttoms by code. Thans in advance.

Comment: @GSandro_Strongs Try this and Check this [link](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/3325/Controls-and-Libraries/Ribbon-Bars-and-Menu/Examples/Ribbon/How-to-Get-Visible-and-All-Ribbon-Pages)
`var ribbonPage = parentRibbon.TotalPageCategory;`

Comment: I try it but it doesn't detect ItemLinks. I modified to List<BarItemLink> var = parentRibbon.TotalPageCategory.ItemLinks.ToList(); but itemLinks doesn't contain a definition

Comment: Hi GSandro, First you need to get ribbon page information then get the group information then using Page and Group information you can retrieve the bar button items
`List<BarItemLink> var = parentRibbon.Pages.GetPageByName("RibbonPageList").Groups.GetGroupByText("RibbonPageGroupList").ItemLinks.ToList();`

Comment: Yes I want to go through no saying name of controls. is it possible? What does RibbonPageList mean?